# How to selectively create a directory, copy files and run a batch file in InnoSetup

Tags: inno-setup

PostgreSQL is bundled into my application, and with InnoSetup, the necessary directories/files are created/copied then Installer runs the required batch file to create a service.
It works well.

### Extracted from my config.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\InternalDatabase"
[Files]
Source: "C:\MyApplication\InternalDatabase\*";         DestDir: "{app}\InternalDatabase"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MyApplication"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "InstallationPath"; ValueData: "{app}" ; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

I have noticed that in case I just need to replace other application binaries, I should not create PostgreSQL's directories/files which is a default action within my InnoSetup config.
So, I am looking for the way I can skip this action if PostgreSQL is already configured in the system(Windows).

Can you let me know how I can Create Directory/Copying Files/Run a batch file selectively?
For now, I think I should put the PostgreSQL registry information, and I should check if there is or not to decide whether I should do all of the default things or just skip the PostgreSQL part.

Any example would be very appreciated.

Comment: The same (`Check` parameter) works for for `Files` section and others.

Comment: You mean I should show 2 options to a user and give him a chance to select the option to be run? Actually, I want to do that silently without user selection. Thank you.

Comment: Ah. "Check" option. I will go over it. Thank you.